# How Executorservice works in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am familiar with the traditional thread implementation but not so sure about Executorservice. I know it's very handy when dealing threads using executor service. But I am little confuse about it's implementation.

Let's assume I have a parent thread/main thread and a executor service which has max thread pool size 10. Now I want to perform a certain task on a jms queue only if it's size is less than 1000. So right now I can probably think to implement this in two ways.

**case 1:**

```
class MyThreadClass inmplements Runnable {
      public static void main(String args[]){
           while(true){
               int checkQueueSize = jmsQueue.getSize();
               while(checkQueueSize<1000){
                   threadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(this);
                   ++checkQueueSize;
               }
           }
      }
      public void run(){
           jmsQueue.pushMessage("Hello Thread");
      }
}
```

**case 2:**

```
class MyThreadClass inmplements Runnable {
          public static void main(String args[]){
            threadPoolTaskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
               threadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(this);
          }
          public void run(){
               while(true){
                   int checkQueueSize = jmsQueue.getSize();
                   while(checkQueueSize<1000){
                       jmsQueue.pushMessage("Hello Thread");
                       ++checkQueueSize;
                   }
               }
          }
    }
```

My understanding is **case 2** will not span more than one thread. Am I correct or not? Or is there other way to perform the task?

Comment: `setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown` is part of the spring framework -  are you asking in that context?

Comment: Yes. but if there any other way it is very welcome.

Comment: Your `while(checkQueueSize<=1000)` statement will loop forever if the local variable, `checkQueueSize` is less than or equal to 1000.  Nothing in the loop can possibly change the value of the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"case 2 will not span more than one thread" Yes. This is correct. Because you call `execute` only once.

In first scenario you may call `execute` many times. And in case of previous task isn't finished additional thread will be runed.

Comment: So can I assume the **case 1**  of implementation is quite perfect?

Comment: I personally prefer not to use "perfect" word, but Yes it is how executor service should be used. Also it have bug in it you should replace inner `while` with `if`. Also it will be good to add some delay or else it will consume lot of processor ticks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I can't replace the inner `while` with `if`, cuz just before the inner `while` there is a `getSize()` method which uses `jmx` connection to get the `jmsQueue` size. So if I replace inner `while` with `if` then it will ask for `jmsQueue` size for each iteration which is a heavy operation. Anyway your suggestion at above in ans field is what I am looking for. So marking it as answeared.

Comment: If you leave your code as is you get infinite loop because value of `checkQueueSize` did not changes in inner loop. Once it got less than 1000 you never leave that loop.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did not notice that. I will change that logic.

Answer (score 0):

Please find my code :-

```
    class MyThreadClass inmplements Runnable {
        public static void main(String args[]){
          threadPoolTaskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
          for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
             threadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(this);
        }
        public void run(){
             while(true){
                 int checkQueueSize = jmsQueue.getSize();

                 if(checkQueueSize<=1000){
                     jmsQueue.pushMessage("Hello Thread");
                 }
             }   
        }
  }
```

Modification:-

1. Create the 10 threads and assign them to run job by passing your  Runnable class object.

   2. Remove unnecessary while loop as the outer loop performing infite itaration.

Comment: It's nice suggestion. But don't you think in this case the threads will never goes to idle state even if there is no task to perform?